# Keyboard backlight not working

Tags: keyboard, backlight

I have just installed Elementary OS 5.0 and surprised how good it is! There is one annoying thing which is the backlight not working. I have tried different solutions that seemed to have worked for others but not for me.

What I have tried:

- install `xbacklight`
- run `sudo xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'`
- run `xset led 3`
- update grub file: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=video"`